# awk :: how to find matching words in two files

Tags: awk

Some good folk here on StackOverflow helped me find common lines in two files using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)]; next} tolower($0) in a' 1.txt 2.txt
```

But how to find common words in two files where words are in line?

For example, let's say that I have `1.txt` with these words:

```
apple
orange
butter
flower
```

And then `2.txt` with these words:

```
dog cat Butter tower
```

How to return `butter` or `Butter`?

I just want to find the common words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file1
apple 
orange 
butter
flower

$ cat file2
dog cat Butter tower
```

I would write it this way:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) words[tolower($i)]; next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (tolower($i) in words) print $i}
' file1 file2
```

Note there is a field by field loop in the case of `FNR==NR` that handles files that may have more than one word per line. If you know that that is not the case, you can simplify to:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{words[tolower($1)]; next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (tolower($i) in words) print $i}
' file1 file2
```

---

If this is not working on Windows it may be an issue with `\r\n` line endings. If `awk` is using a `RS=[\n]` value then the the `\r` is left on all words at the end of a line; `butter\r` does not match `butter`.

Try:

```
awk -v RS='[ \r\n\t]' 'FNR==NR{words[tolower($0)]; next}
                       tolower($0) in words' file1 file2
```

---

Comments on your WSL comments in the link:

Your workarounds for Unix files on DOS are many.

Create `file1` with DOS line endings this way:

```
$ printf 'apple\r\norange\r\nbutter\r\nflower\r\n' >file1
```

Now you can test / see the file has those line endings with `cat -v`:

```
$ cat -v file1
apple^M
orange^M
butter^M
flower^M
```

You can also remove those line endings with `sed`, `perl`, `awk`, etc. Here is a `awk` removing the `\r` from the files:

```
$ cat -v <(awk 1 RS='\r\n' ORS='\n' file1)
apple
orange
butter
flower
```

A `sed` and `perl`:

```
$ cat -v <(sed 's/\r$//' file1)
#same
```

or

```
$ cat -v <(perl -0777 -lpe 's/\r\n/\n/g' file1)
```

etc. Then use that same construct with awk-on-windows:

```
awk 'your_awk_program' <(awk 1 RS='\r\n' ORS='\n' file1) <(awk 1 RS='\r\n' ORS='\n' file2)
```

The downside: While each input is treated as a different logical file, so the `FNR==NR` awk test still works, the awk special variable `FILENAME` is lost in the process. If you want to keep `FILENAME` associated with the actual file, you need to preprocess the files prior to feeding to awk or deal with the `\r` inside your awk script.

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite sure that someone with 77.8k points on StackOverflow know his stuffs. Unfortunately your code is returning me nothing: https://snipboard.io/6YUOg1.jpg. 
I'm using WSL2 on Windows10, if you tell me this is working on your end this looks like a bug on WSL2? What do you think

Comment: have you tested this on Linux  (not WSL) for the same 2 files?

Comment: It definitely works on Mac OS. Your likely issue is the Windows `'\r\n'` line endings and the file is not be interpreted correctly on your awk.

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##Tc4xC4MwFATgufkVNwhRnOxq06GDo4Nr6RA10UclkRixIP72VBRKp8fBx92r5dSHoJregstxHBSYddJ0@61n75VjerCLchx3TYPKwNiJW9uhkR6PQ8H/oeuO5PIGL8pKiLJaF@va6ent0RRHWfLKYdTHb@yCVVuHmESW002URU5pmoA04h@nPRscHQlGR8Yjoo1xnA@diyF8AQ)

Comment: tested now, your last code is working! This is definitely a problem with `'\r\n'` line endings in WSL on Windows

Answer (score 2):

This `grep` should do the job:

```sh
grep -oiwFf 1.txt 2.txt

Butter
```

Or else this simple `gnu awk` would also work:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NR==FNR {w[tolower($1)]; next} tolower($1) in w' 1.txt 2.txt

Butter
```

Comment: I can hear you @anubhava and thank you for your help, it looks like none of the two commands works: https://snipboard.io/XA6PHO.jpg if you see the comments on the other two reply you will see that we have apparently hit a strange way how that WSL handles `\r\n` line endings. I will probably flag this to Microsoft because it goes by itself that a lot of shell commands like `grep` or `awk` will be unusable. Let me know what you think

Comment: That's very nice @FrancescoMantovani

Comment: btw my suggested awk command here works fine with files ending with `\r\n` because `[[:space:]]` matches `\r` also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over every field per line (of 2.txt) and check:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)];next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i) in a){print $i}}}' \
    1.txt 2.txt
```

An alternative way to do this in awk would be to add whitespace to the input record separator when processing the 2nd file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)];next} tolower($0) in a' 1.txt  RS="[\n ]" 2.txt
```

Comment: The same for you, thank you for your help and 131k on StackOveflow talk by themself, I think I'm hitting a bug on `awk` on WSL2 on Windows10: https://snipboard.io/MiHhyW.jpg

Comment: can you confirm your command is working on Linux (not WSL) for the same 2 files?

Comment: make  sure your data files are clean with `dos2unix 1.txt 2.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, nice tip, I tested now with `dos2unix` and the problem is not there: https://snipboard.io/MODBic.jpg

Comment: Hey @FrancescoMantovani! Sorry for not answering earlier, I will look at that